# Error al imprimir en widnows mediante PHP escpos

Tags: php, print, imprimir

estoy intentando imprimir mediante PHP en windows, para ello estoy usando la librería **escpos-php** de PHP. La cuestión es que puedo imprimir, pero necesito que me imprima un pdf o un archivo .html, pero no me error en ambos.

Error cuando intento imprimir un pdf:

> loadPdf requires imagick extension.

Error cuando intento imprimir un html:

> You require xvfb-run but it could not be found

He intentado buscar solución pero sigue igual.

Nota: el código qur utilizo es el que me viene de ejemplo en el githug de escpos.

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo, servidor web y PHP usas? La extensión debe activarse en el `php.ini`. En cuanto a `xvfb-run` siento decirte que es una utilidad de linux, entiendo que si te la solicita espera que el servidor corra bajo linux y trata de ejecutar [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

Comment: Estoy en windows en modo local y uso xampp. Y estoy usando 7. Gracias

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103796/are-there-differences-between-xvfb-and-xvfb-run